# C# "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors"

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate, aws-iot

Need to publish message from .net core to aws using pfx certificate. getting error when connecting to client id.

My source code from worker service is given below

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                DateTime registryValue = DateTime.Now;
                try
                {
                    string application = Configuration[Constants.Application];
                    string sourceName = Configuration[Constants.SourceName];
                    string certificateSubject = Configuration[Constants.CertificateSubject];
                    string iotEndPoint = Configuration[Constants.IotEndpoint];
                    int brokerPort = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration[Constants.BrokerPort]);
                    string topic = Configuration[Constants.Topic];
                    string ggcRootCaCertificate = Configuration[Constants.GgcRootCaCertificate];
                    string storeName = Configuration[Constants.X509Store];
                    string clientId = Configuration[Constants.ClientId];


                    Logger.LogInformation($"ggcRootCaCertificate: {ggcRootCaCertificate}.");

                    string machineName = Environment.MachineName;
                    EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(application, machineName);
                    EventLogEntryCollection eventLogEntryCollection = eventLog.Entries;
                    //int logCount = eventLogEntryCollection.Count;

                    //if (logCount <= 0)
                    //{
                    //    Logger.LogInformation("No Event Logs in the Log :");
                    //}

                    X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                    var clientCert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(x =>
                                      x.SubjectName.Name.Contains(certificateSubject));

                    if (clientCert == null)
                    {
                        Logger.LogInformation("Certificate not installed in the system");
                    }

                    X509Certificate x509Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Path.Join(ggcRootCaCertificate));
                    MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(iotEndPoint, brokerPort, true, x509Certificate, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);

                    if (clientId == null)
                    {
                        clientId = machineName;
                    }
                    mqttClient.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1_1;
                    mqttClient.Connect(clientId);
                    Logger.LogInformation($"Connected to AWS IoT with client id: {clientId}.");

                    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(Constants.RegistryPath);
                    DateTime calculatedLogTime = DateTime.Now;

                    EventLog log = new EventLog(application);
                    var totalEntries = log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                         .Where(x => x.Source == sourceName)
                         .Select(x => new
                         {
                             x.MachineName,
                             x.Site,
                             x.Source,
                             x.Message,
                             x.TimeGenerated,
                             x.TimeWritten
                         }).ToList();

                    registryValue = Convert.ToDateTime(registryKey.GetValue(Constants.LastEventLogFetch));

                    if (totalEntries.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        List<dynamic> termsList = new List<dynamic>();

                        if (registryValue == null || registryValue == DateTime.MinValue)
                        {
                            var Entries = totalEntries.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeGenerated).FirstOrDefault();
                            mqttClient.Publish(topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($" {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Entries.Message)}"));
                            Logger.LogInformation("Message published", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($" {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Entries.Message)}"));
                            registryKey.SetValue(Constants.LastEventLogFetch, calculatedLogTime.AddMinutes(-1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            calculatedLogTime = registryValue.AddMinutes(1);
                            var Entries = totalEntries.Where(x => (x.TimeGenerated <= calculatedLogTime && x.TimeGenerated >= registryValue)).ToList();
                            if (Entries.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Entries.GetRange(0, Entries.Count))
                                {
                                    termsList.Add(item.Message + "Message from vm 30.31");
                                }
                                mqttClient.Publish(topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($" {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(termsList)}"));
                                Logger.LogInformation("Message published", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($" {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(termsList)}"));
                                registryKey.SetValue(Constants.LastEventLogFetch, calculatedLogTime);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Logger.LogInformation("Event log count is zero. Can't send message");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Logger.LogInformation("Event log count is zero");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogInformation(ex.Message, DateTimeOffset.Now);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                Logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                if (registryValue > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(60000, stoppingToken);
                    Logger.LogInformation("Registry value is greater than current time. So task delay will be one minue");
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
                    Logger.LogInformation("Registry value is less than current time. So task delay will be one second");
                }
            }
        }
```

Json settings is goen below,

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AccuTabSettings": {
    "Application": "name",
    "SourceName": "Source",
    "CertificateSubject": "CN=AWS IoT Certificate",
    "IotEndpoint": "1.1.1.1",
    "BrokerPort": 800,
    "Topic": "device/client_id",
    "GgcRootCaCertificate": "F:\\Certificates\\ggc-root.ca.crt",
    "X509Store": "MY",
    "ClientId": "pqr"
  }
}
```

When connecting client getting issue => "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primary problem with `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` error is because of subject mismatch between subject specified in remote certificate and address you are connecting to. I suspect that remote certificate is issued against some DNS name, but you are connecting to IP address which apparently isn't specified in certificate subject/SAN extension. You need to ensure that remote certificate's SAN extension contains the address you are connecting to.

There is insufficient information to debug `RemoteCertificateChainErrors` error. You need to attach a debugger and retrieve exact errors.